# how to display data from a NSMutablearray in a Table View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to initialize a tableview with an image, name and surname of each user that I have stored in a NSMutableArray.
In this mutablearray I save a class that I created to store users data and its schema is as follows:

```
ResultSearchController{
  NSInteger *userID;
  NSString *userName;
  NSString *userSurname;
  NSString *userThumb;
}
```

I have read the documentation of TableView but I still have doubts and problems to display the data in TableView (seems rather complicated to use such objects). Could you help me to get started with this?
Thanks!!

Comment: write some code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`...

Comment: Agreed. You need to look at the delegate and datasource methods. This allows you to modify each cell in turn. If you use the row of the cell as the index for you NSMutableArray, then write modification code. it should modify each cell as the table view requires it.

Comment: Please see [this](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/) and [this](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/introduction-to-table-view/) and [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/3481-uitableview-tutorial-part-2-a.html) and [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/) and [this](https://www.google.es/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=uitableview+example)

Comment: My major problem is that my English is not very good and I have problems understanding. Thanks again!

Comment: Use google Translate then ....

Comment: I'm on it, I wasn't asking for a translation ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have a Custom UITableViewCell for that.

Simply use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate of UITableView (to set the image):-

```
yourCustomCellObject.yourImageViewINCustCell.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[(yourClassToStoreData *)[yourNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] userThumb]];
```

Similarly you can do in the same manner to set other control elements.

It's just an example of how you can do.I am assuming you have stored the data over some class objects and adding it to an NSMtableArray.